# Cannot parse json sent from a channel

Tags: python, google-app-engine, channel-api

Ok in my python code. I have this

```
   foo = "aaa"; //foo and bar are variables that change, just an example here
   bar = "bbb";
   json = {"here": foo, "there": bar} //also tried single quotes
   message = simplejson.dumps(json) //also tried just json instead of simplejson
   channel.send_message(user_id(), message)
```

In javascript

```
 onMessage = function(m) {
    var a = JSON.parse(m.data);
    alert(a.here); // foo should pop up but it doesnt
  }
```

It seems like the parse method does not work. No alert that pops up. If I remove parse line and put this than alert pops up, if I just change alert and keep parse it still doest do anything;

```
alert(m.data) // this prints out {"here": "aaa", "there": "bbb"}
```

So idk why it is not parsing right. I am assuming it has something to do with quotes. I guess I am having trouble with them again.

**UPDATE**

please look at my answer below, i solved the problem.

Comment: you can now just 'import json' rather then simplejson on app engine FYI.

Comment: yeah i tried that too. didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried just hard coding the data in ``var a = JSON.parse(m.data)`` thus disproving your worries about JSON.parse not working.

Comment: as i said alert(m.data) prints out {"here": "aaa", "there": "bbb"}

Comment: so m.data is actually a string. i dont think the problem is there

Comment: yeah if i do like that. it works. but within the google app engine, using that method(onMessage). and sending it from python (server) to javascript (client) doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I resolved this problem like this;

```
var a = JSON.parse(String(m.data));
```

looks like m.data is not a string after all, so you need to cast it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try that:

`alert (m.data['here']);`